# I get a segmentation fault when I compile and try to run this code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is a part of my code:

```
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        for(k = 0; k < rows - i && k < columns - j; k++)
        {
            if(i + k > rows || j + k > columns) break;
            if(b->board[i + k][j + k] == 1) counter++;
            if(b->board[i + k][j + k] == 2) counter = 0;
            if(counter > max_pd)
            {
                plh = counter;
                jkee = j;
                kkee = k;
            }
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
    if(plh > max_pd)
    {
        max_pd = plh;
        plh = 0;
        for(n = 0; n < 1; n++)
        {
            if(i + kkee > rows || jkee + kkee + 1 > columns) break;
            if(b->board[i + kkee + 1][jkee + kkee + 1] == 0 && b->board[i + kkee][jkee + kkee + 1] != 0) play_pd = jkee + kkee + 1;
        }
    }
    counter = 0;
    plh = 0;
    jkee = 0;
    kkee = 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault when I try to run this code at the line :

```
if(b->board[i + kkee + 1][jkee + kkee + 1] == 0 && b->board[i + kkee][jkee + kkee + 1] != 0) play_pd = jkee + kkee + 1;
```

However in the exact above line I clearly state that if the numbers put in board are not in there, break.

(the board is defined in a struct like this: b->board[rows][columns])

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us. Including the how you define and initialize the arrays or pointers, their sizes, and also when you catch the crash in your debugger, check the values of all indexes and include them in the question.

Comment: Having a loop `for(n = 0; n < 1; n++)` that only runs once, and then not using `n` either looks wrong. As do a lot of those `+ 1`, C array indices start at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```c
if(i + kkee > rows || jkee + kkee + 1 > columns) break;
if(b->board[i + kkee + 1][jkee + kkee + 1] == 0 && b->board[i + kkee][jkee + kkee + 1] != 0) play_pd = jkee + kkee + 1;
```

The index for the row an column of the bord must be respectively `< rows` and `< columns`.

The test to break should be

```
if(i + kkee + 1 >= rows || jkee + kkee + 1 >= columns) break;
```

This will ensure that the next instruction will not use indexes out of bounds.

You have the same problem above with the instructions:

```c
if(i + k > rows || j + k > columns) break;
if(b->board[i + k][j + k] == 1) counter++;
if(b->board[i + k][j + k] == 2) counter = 0;
```

The test for the break should be

```
if(i + k >= rows || j + k >= columns) break;
```

Comment: Seems like when I fixed that, in another line I had the same mistake, but as soon as I fixed that too, my code runs perfectly. Thanks a lot.